# How can I enable the query widget in MapGuide Maestro 6.0?

Tags: javascript, viewer, mapguide

I'm doing a viewer with MapGuide Maestro, I need an option to do querys inside the viewer.

I already looked everywhere and I can't find anything, in some youtube videos, the option to do querys is available using fusion projects, but in my projects it does not show.

If someone can help me with anything would be welcome, I'm starting in this world so a lots of thing are new to me.

Big thanks to everyone.